# Can I use .sql query file as a data source in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a fairly sizeable query saved as a .sql file (in SQL Server 2019).  I would like to use this file as a data source in SSIS. Is this possible?  If so, how can I do this?

Comment: As a data source? .sql files are just text files so use a text file source, as you would with a CSV, if you want to use it as a data source.

Comment: Not directly as a data source.  There's no data.  You'd have to read the file in as text, read the query, then execute it.

Comment: You need to take a little time to experiment with SSIS. You can deifnitely use a SQL query in a file as a source. I would recommend creating it as a view instead though.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid For some reason this solution did not cross my mind, but it seems so obvious now that you said it.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use script task to read file into a parameter:

```
string sql = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("[path]");
```